# Why "Traceback (most recent call last):" error comes even when you write correct code to automate application using python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is my program I am trying to click on forgot password link using link text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service_obj = Service("Downloads.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service =service_obj)
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client/auth/login")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Forgot password?").click()
```

I am trug to reach forgot password screen from login screen using automation python with selenium but I am getting below error after running the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\938861\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Locatorsextension.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Forgot password?").click()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\938861\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\938861\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\938861\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Forgot password?"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0064ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x005DEE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x004DB7BD+571325]
    Ordinal0 [0x0050AC2F+764975]
    Ordinal0 [0x0050AE1B+765467]
    Ordinal0 [0x0053D0F2+970994]
    Ordinal0 [0x00527364+881508]
    Ordinal0 [0x0053B56A+963946]
    Ordinal0 [0x00527136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x004FFEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x00500F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008FEED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008F0D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006DA03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006D8DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x005E682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x005EB128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x005EB215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x005F6484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C77D69+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7710BB9B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7710BB1F+191]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The most relevant part of that error message is the `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Forgot password?"}` and not the "Traceback" you mention in your title. Also please try to tag questions with appropriate (language/library/...) tags in the future. "Traceback" as the only tag is not very useful.

Comment: It comes because you didn't "write correct code". It's important to read the traceback, not assume that everything you wrote is correct. Even if the code is "correct", you don't know what the server might respond with in certain cases, so you need to handle them

Comment: Also https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client/auth/login points to a 404 page for me. Of course your test won't find a "Forgot password" link there.

Answer (score 0):

But that code *isn't* correct. You need to consider the case where your Forgot password link isn't found. Per the docs, [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) raises an exception if the element isn't found. The `NoSuchElementException` is to be expected.

You could catch that error and implement your own error policy. Perhaps a friendly message and exit, as in

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import sys

service_obj = Service("Downloads.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service =service_obj)
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client/auth/login")
try:
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Forgot password?").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Error: Could not find forgot password link", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(2)
```